# Как получить объект класса с помощью рефлексии (для вызова нестатичного метода)?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Код:

```
public static void runAllAnnotatedMethods() throws Exception {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("fillers.ArrayFiller");
    Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : m) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Filler.class)) {
            // массив `int[] a` создается рандомно в статическом методе и находиться по аннотации @Filler
            int[] a = (int[]) method.invoke(null);
            //в пакете sorters ищу все классы, унаследованы от Sort(там разные методы сортировки массива)
            Set<Class<? extends Sort>> subTypesOf = (new Reflections("sorters")).getSubTypesOf(Sort.class);
            //предполагаемое объявление объекта(скорее не правильное)
            Object objectToInvokeOn= subTypesOf;
            for (Class c1 : subTypesOf) {
                Method[] m1 = c1.getDeclaredMethods();
                for (Method method1 : m1) {
                if (a != null) {
                    //попытка вызвать не статический метод, параметр которого тот массив а 
                    method1.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, a);
                    long count = System.nanoTime() - start;
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
```

Хотела разобраться сама, но не получается. Не могу понять откуда брать object для invoke. Ошибка в строке `method1.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, a);`

Вот пример класса, метод которого надо вызвать(все эти классы наследуются от Sort):

```
public class ArraySort extends Sort {
    public void arraySort(int[] a){
        Arrays.sort(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Метод вызывается всегда на каком-то объекте, правильно? `objectToInvokeOn` - это и есть объект, метод которого вы собираетесь вызвать. Если вы делаете автоматический поиск и вызов аннотированных методов, у вас должно быть что-то вроде DI-контейнера, в котором лежат экземпляры проаннотированных классов. В самом простом случае — `Map<Class<Z>, Z>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Без рефлексии метод вызывается так:

```
//получаем массив
int[] a 
//вызываем конструктор для создания объекта
ArraySort objectToInvokeOn = new ArraySort();
//вызываем метод с переданными значениями
objectToInvokeOn.arraySort(a);
```

Соответственно, чтобы получить `objectToInvokeOn` нужно вызвать конструктор класса `ArraySort`.

Чтобы сделать это через рефлексию нужно сделать следующее (по шагам):

1. Получить класс

   `subTypesOf` представляет из себя не один, а множество классов (`Set<Class<? extends Sort>>`. В коде уже есть цикл, который перебирает классы по одному, в нем и нужно создавать объекты:

   ```
   for(Class<? extends Sort> c1 : set) {
   ```

   Чтобы не терять информацию о типе заменил `Class` на `Class<? extends Sort>`.
2. Получить конструктор

   У класса `ArraySort` есть конструктор по-умолчанию (публичный, без аргументов). Его можно получить с помощью метода [`Class.getConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-):

   ```
   Constructor<? extends Sort> emptyConstructor = c1.getConstructor();
   ```

   Если у какого-либо из найденных классов не будет такого конструктора, то нужно будет понять как должны создаваться объекты класса и вызвать соответствующие методы/конструкторы.
3. Вызвать конструктор

   Конструктор вызывается методом [`Constructor.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-):

   ```
   Sort objectToInvokeOn = emptyConstructor.newInstance();
   ```

   Опять-таки, здесь используется конструктор без аргументов. Для вызова конструктора с аргументами их нужно передать в `newInstance`.

После всех этих манипуляций для каждого класса получен объект типа `Sort` от которого можно выполнять нестатичные методы.

**Улучшение:** использование `Sort`.

Сейчас `Sort` используется только для поиска классов. При этом у найденных классов вызываются все объявленные методы, что может быть неудобно если у классов будут другие функции кроме сортировки.

Вместо этого можно воспользоваться тем что через рефлексию уже получен объект класса `Sort` от которого можно вызывать методы `Sort` напрямую.

Для этого нужно объявить метод сортировки непосредственно в `Sort`. При этом сделать класс и метод абстрактными, чтобы наследники в обязательном порядке реализовали свою сортировку:

```
abstract class Sort {
    abstract void arraySort(int[] a);
}
```

если в `Sort` нет других методов/полей, то можно преобразовать `Sort` в интерфейс.

После этого можно не перебирать методы через рефлексию, а сразу вызвать нужный от объекта-сортировщика:

```
objectToInvokeOn.sortArray(a);
```

P.S. если стоит задача проверять сортировщики, то нужно будет копировать изначальное состояние массива `a`, иначе все сортировщики кроме первого будут получать уже отсортированный массив.