# wrong number of arguments при вызове метода через рефлексию

Tags: java, рефлексия

Используя рефлексию вызываю методы, которые сортируют переданный массив a:

```
Set <Class <? extends Sort>> subTypesOf = (new Reflections("sorters")).getSubTypesOf(Sort.class);
for (Class <? extends Sort> c1 : subTypesOf) {
  Constructor <? extends Sort> emptyConstructor = c1.getConstructor();
  Sort objectToInvokeOn = emptyConstructor.newInstance();
  Method[] m1 = c1.getDeclaredMethods();
  for (Method method1: m1) {
    if (a != null) {

    System.out.println(c1.getName() + "." + method1.getName());
    method1.setAccessible(true);
    method1.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, new Object[] {a});
```

Ошибка на строке `method1.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, new Object[]{a});` :

```
sorters.ExchangeSort.exchange
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)...
```

Вот класс с методом `exchange`:

```
public class ExchangeSort extends Sort {
    public ExchangeSort() {

    }

    public void exchangeSort(int[] a) {
        exchange(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

      private int[] exchange(int[] a, int begin, int end) {
        int i = begin;
        int j = end;
        int average = (i - (i - j) / 2);
        if (i < j) {
            while ((i < average) && (a[i] <= a[average])) i++;
            while ((j > average) && (a[j] >= a[average])) j--;

            if (i > j) {
                swap(a, i, j);
            }
            if (i == average) {
                average = j;
            } else if (j == average) {
                average = i;
            }
            if (begin >= average) {
                return a;
            }
            return exchange(a, 0, average);
        }
        return exchange(a, average + 1, a.length - 1);
    }
```

Как решить проблему?

Мне нужно вызвать только методы, в которые передается массив `int a[]`(все публичные), и `getMethods()` не подходит, т.к. есть public swap метод в наследнике Sort и тогда он тоже извлекается и пишет ту же ошибку.

Нашла, что можно добавить `method1.setAccessible(true);`, чтобы не извлекались приватные методы, но это не устранило ошибку.

Comment: method1.setAccessible(true); - это не причем. у вас неправильное количество аргументов при рефлексионном вызове... выложите код, который позволит воспроизвести проблему, все запустим. иначе будете спрашивать долго и нудно. в таком виде можно только догадки строить...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Поиск метода по аргументам**

Проблема в том, что в найденном классе вызываются все методы подряд, неважно предназначены они для сортировки или нет. Т.к. о вызываемом методе ничего не известно этот подход крайне ненадежен и небезопасен.

Можно получить список типов аргументов метода через [`Method.getParameterTypes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes--) и отсеять неподходящие.

```
Class<?>[] arguments = method1.getParameterTypes();
//если не один аргумент, пропускаем
if(arguments.length!=1) continue;
//если один, но не массив, тоже пропускаем
if(arguments[0]!=int[].class) continue;
System.out.println...
```

Либо использовать [`Class.getMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-), который ищет метод с заданными именем и типами аргументов. При таком подходе методы с другим списком аргументов вызваны не будут. Тем не менее, от ошибок вызова это не убережет, т.к. список аргументов мало о чем говорит:

```
public void exchangeSort(int[] a) {
     ...
public void killEveryone(int[] a) {
```

**Человеческий подход: использовать `Sort`**

К классу `Sort` есть обращения как в классе-сортировщике, так и в вызывающем классе. При этом класс никак не используется. Будет логично если в этом классе будет объявлен метод сортировки `void sort. В этом случае рефлексия будет использоваться для поиска классов-наследников и создания объектов, а сортировка будет выполняться вызовом метода.

Подробнее о подходе я писал в [ответе на другой Ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768836/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#768876) на такую же тему.

**Альтернатива: аннотация**

Для заполнения массива уже используется поиск аннотированного метода. Так же можно поступить и сортировкой. Создайте аннотацию `Sorter` и отмечайте ей методы сортировки

```
@Sorter
public void exchangeSort(int[] a) {
```

Comment: Method.getParameterTypes очень помог! спасибо!